# Browser inconsistency when using JavaScript to generate JavaScript to generate inline style

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I'm developing an app that assigns users different colored text (think Gravatar-like hash-generated user colors) [i.e. [HashColors](http://jsbin.com/gahigi/12/edit?html,output) - may have to click "Run with JS"].

To integrate the HashColors script into the larger app, I created a function that sets the `.textContent` and `.style` for each user's entry.  `.textContent` appears to work cross-browser, but `.style` appears to only work in Firefox.

A full example is available at https://jsbin.com/sudave/9/edit?html,console,output (may have to click "Run with JS"), but I'm pretty sure the crux of my problem is within the following function or how I call it:

*Element generation function:*

```
var gE = function(selector, value, style) {
    var element = document.querySelector("ul " + selector);
    element.textContent = value || " ";  // <-- works as expected
    element.style = style || "";  // <-- does NOT work as expected !!!
                                  // i.e. works as expected in FF
                                  // does NOT work as expected in Chrome or Safari
    return element;
};
```

*Example element generation function call:*

```
 gE('.name', "White on Purple", "background: rgba(" + color + "); color: white");
```

where `var color = "100, 000, 100, 100";`

**Can anybody tell me why this works as expected in Firefox, but not in other browsers?  Better yet, can anybody make suggestions so that I can get it working cross-browser?**

*Working as expected in Firefox:*

[image: Working as expected in Firefox]

*NOT working as expected in Chrome:*

[image]

Comment: Why not generate a CSS rule instead?

Comment: @SLaks - First - Thank you for your answer below!  To answer your question - because each user (and it's likely there will be many users visible per page) will have their own color, and that color will be used as a background in one context and a text color in a different context, it seemed most appropriate to inline the actual style.   (Check out [HashColors](http://jsbin.com/gahigi/12/edit?html,output) to get a better idea of what I'm talking about.)

Comment: It is likely to be more efficient to dynamically generate a CSS stylesheet, especially if new comments might be added later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Element.style` property returns an object with a property for each style; not a string.

You should call `setAttribute("style", style)` instead to actually set the attribute.

Comment: For those interested, here's the [corrected example](https://jsbin.com/sudave/edit?html,console,output).